# Step-by-step functional testing automation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, testing, tdd

I have a basic class in C# from which I create inherited classes for databinding scenarios. You can think of it as a substitute for .NET's `DataRow` class.

I want to automate testing of a typical row's lifetime, making sure that things such as object state and changes detection remains coherent throughout.

My first thought was to simply use unit test class with a method that would do multiple operations and consequent assertions, like this:

```
/*
For the sake of keeping this as simple as possible, let's just assume
that new instances can be created with a public constructor, as "unchanged".
*/

var row = new PocoTest(); // Derived from aforementionned base class

Assert.AreEqual(RecordStates.Unchanged, row.RecordState);
Assert.IsFalse(row.IsPropertyModified("MyProperty"));

row.MyProperty = "this is a new value";

Assert.AreEqual(RecordStates.Modified, row.RecordState);
Assert.IsTrue(row.IsPropertyModified("MyProperty"));

row.AcceptChanges();

Assert.AreEqual(RecordStates.Unchanged, row.RecordState);
Assert.IsFalse(row.IsPropertyModified("MyProperty"));
```

However, this doesn't feel right in the unit testing paradigm in which it is recommended to have only one thing at a time being tested.

So I'm kind of looking for some advice, here. Am I overthinking this? Should I just keep doing it this way? Or is there another, better and more adapted way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your tests should each be testing one logical thing. This may require several steps or assertions to verify. This is fine.

However your tests look to me like 3 tests. 1 which verifies that upon creation the property is unchanged, and then one which verifies that when its changed the object reflects that and then one which verifies that after accepting changes the state is unchanged again.

What have you called your test currently. I suspect that you have had trouble giving it a name, or it has a long convoluted name. Splitting it it should give you nice descriptive names.

I'd go with this:

```
public void WhenRowIsCreatedItShouldBeInAnUnchangedState()
{
  var row = new PocoTest(); // Derived from aforementionned base class

  Assert.AreEqual(RecordStates.Unchanged, row.RecordState);
  Assert.IsFalse(row.IsPropertyModified("MyProperty"));
}


public void WhenPropertyIsChangedItShouldBeInAModifiedState()
{
  var row = new PocoTest(); // Derived from aforementionned base class
  row.MyProperty = "this is a new value";

  Assert.AreEqual(RecordStates.Modified, row.RecordState);
  Assert.IsTrue(row.IsPropertyModified("MyProperty"));
}

public void WhenChangesAreAcceptedItShouldBeInAnUnchangedState()
{
  var row = new PocoTest(); // Derived from aforementionned base class
  row.MyProperty = "this is a new value";
  row.AcceptChanges();

  Assert.AreEqual(RecordStates.Unchanged, row.RecordState);
  Assert.IsFalse(row.IsPropertyModified("MyProperty"));
}
```

Comment: I was doing just that before asking here. The problem is that this is a rather small portion of a much more thorough method. Later on, the same object would be added to a special collection that's granted access to some of its internal functions and have the ability to act on its state. Somehow I was hoping I could test how the class reacted to multiple manipulations and ensure that its state, data check methods and the likes would remain consequent at ALL times, *even* (and especially) when going through a lot of different manipulations.

Comment: Of course I could repeat the same block over and over in different methods, each having one or two assertions, but it would be way too redundant to my taste. :/

Comment: If you test each interaction individually why would running many of them not work as expected? Unless the manipulations are happening on multiple threads at the same time, in which case you probably want different tests anyway.

Comment: Because as I said, each "individual" actions change the object's state, and state won't be maintained between individual unit tests on it.

Comment: But your tests are testing an individual action. Once you have tested an action and proved its correctness, why would a previous action (which moves your object from one state to the another) affect the next action? your tests should set up the initial state you need and validate the behaviour of applying the action. If an action needs multiple tests to validate its behaviour against different starting states then so be it, but I think you are better trying to stick to testing one action in your tests.

Comment: It *would* work but it also would mean lots of redundant code. Here's an example: the object has a `IsLoading` flag that's `true` when object properties are set while loading data from a store. I need to assert that during that phase, no changing events are raised, no dirty flag are set, the version remains unchanged, the `IsEditing` flag stays `false`, the `IDataErrorInfo` implementation has no errors and the `IsPropertyModified` method = `false`. That's *six* tests having the same starting point (data load). I haven't done any actual writing tests yet, which will *also* require data load.

Comment: As I said above you can have multiple physical assertions in a logical assertion. So if whilst loading you should not be able to call a few other methods you *might* be able to verify all of those in a single test. Although I'd still prefer one test per assertion in the examples you gave I think. If the issue is code duplication thenI would approach this the same as any other code duplication issue in the code, and try and remove the duplication  by  moving it to a method or base class. If you had a `DoDefaultDataLoad()` method you could call this in each test, or place all your data loading..

Comment: ... tests in a single class and put the data load logic in a test setup method. Even with the duplication I still think its better to have small focused unit tests as then when something goes wrong, you know immediately which thing has the problem. If the setup and assertions are all in one method then you might not know what has failed, or fix a failure only to get another one immediately as the test is progressing a little further.

Answer (score 2):

I'll have to be controversial here - I think the "one test, one test method" is a dogma rather than a useful tool. Its a matter of whether your test is whole, complete and predictable. I'd say go with your current approach - after all what is to be gained by splitting it up and adding complexity. Your code currently has lower cyclomatic complexity than adding in an extra function call for each Assert.

Comment: Controversial or not, I think that's a pretty valid opinion. In fact, mine is getting closer every day. :) It's just that I'm pretty new to unit testing and wanted to make sure I wasn't missing on some MSTest feature that's more appropriate for my scenario.